# Offline logout with JWT auth on mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile, jwt, logout

Does anyone have a particular technique for offline logout on a mobile application that has a jwt token based authentication ? Or do you have any advice ?

Comment: Can't you simply discard the token?

Comment: @Paulw11by "discard" you mean deleting it from the device ? Because the backend doesn't know when a user goes offline.

Comment: But the device is offline, so it can't tell the backend anything. Normally the client side just discards the token, so that next time it tries to access the backend (when it is back online) the user is required to authenticate as the client doesn't have a valid token.  Being "logged in" and being "online" are different things. If the backend needs to know if a user is online then you need some sort of persistent connection.

Comment: Yes i got your point. Discarding the token on the device seems to be right thing to do. But if the app supports push notifications, the backend will keep sending push notification to that logged out user. I think it can require a bit more logic from there.

Comment: So that is a slightly different question. It helps us if you put all of the details in your question to start with. If the device is offline then it isn’t going to receive notifications until it comes back online. You could send silent notifications that your app turns into local notifications. Include the target userid in the notification so that the client can ignore it if the user has logged out/changed.

Comment: Yes. Thats what i call "a bit more logic". Thank you for answer. Very Helpful I found this post that tries to solve the problem. https://android.jlelse.eu/solving-offline-logout-problem-f3b50da49e7e

Answer (score 0):

Found a pretty good solution following  [this post](https://android.jlelse.eu/solving-offline-logout-problem-f3b50da49e7e). And combined to what @Paulw11 said you must be able to solve this.